# Code Execution stops after axios 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios

I'm using `axios` with `trycatch` but when the api returns 500 internal server error, the code execution flows to catch but outside the `async` function code doesn't execute, I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
export async function authRequest(router, path='/', data={}, method='get') {

  const authKey = getAuthKey();

  try {
    const request = await axios({
      method,
      url: apiUrl + path,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + authKey
      },
      data
    });

    return request.data;
  } catch (error) {

    const isLogged = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: apiUrl + '/isLoggedUser',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + authKey
      }
    });

    if (isLogged.data == false) {
      router.push({
        name: 'login'
      })
    } else {
      console.error('Cannot process this request');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Calling this function:

```
const req = await authRequest(
    this.$router,
    '/video/play',
  );

console.log('cannot reach to this statment after 500 error in axios request')
```

As the last `console.log` statement doesn't execute/reach or any code after when `Axios` throws 500 internal server error.

**Please note that: the problem is with axios 500 internal server that stops further code execution outside the `authRequest` function.**

Answer (score -1):

The Axios request you are making in the catch block should be surrounded by try/catch. Any response other than `2XX` will go to catch block(throws error).

[For more about this](https://github.com/axios/axios)

```
export async function authRequest(router, path = '/', data = {}, method = 'get') {

  const authKey = getAuthKey();

  try {
    const request = await axios({
      method,
      url: apiUrl + path,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + authKey
      },
      data
    });

    return request.data;
  } catch (error) {

    try {
      const isLogged = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: apiUrl + '/isLoggedUser',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': "Bearer " + authKey
        }
      });

      if (isLogged.data == false) {
        router.push({
          name: 'login'
        })
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Cannot process this request');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Can you try by using try/catch when you are calling the `authRequest`.

```
try{

    const req = await authRequest(
    this.$router,
    '/video/play',
  );
  console.log('cannot reach to this statment after 500 error in axios request')
}
catch(e){
    console.log('cannot reach to this statment after 500 error in axios request')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that `axios` request in `catch block` is not a problem and it returns `200 status code`, by the way I tried your solution as well and still outside this `async authRequest` function the code is not executing

Comment: @SyedAqeel can  you try using try/catch while calling `authRequest`

Comment: Yes, I also tried `trycatch` when calling the `authRequest` function but the problem still is same, the code doesn't execute after the function call when axios throws error inside the function

Comment: are you calling `authRequest` in async function?

Comment: Yes, it's in async function

Comment: what does `getAuthKey` does? can `getAuthKey` throw error. If yes then add it to try block.

Comment: `getAuthKey` return only a key from localStorage, and the problem is only with axios 500 internal server, and this is the thing that stops further code execution outside the `authRequest` function